# Out of bounds exception in this code

Tags: java

I'm trying to return the string if the word "bread" appears on either side of the word, so for example: getSandwich("breadjambread") → "jam" 
but the code that I wrote keeps giving me out of bounds exceptions.  How can I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
public String getSandwich(String str) {
  String tmp = "";
  String newString = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
    if (str.length() >= 11 && str.substring(i, i+6).equals("bread")) {
      tmp = str.substring(i+6);
    }
    if (tmp.length() > 0 && tmp.substring(i+1, i+7).equals("bread")) {
      newString = tmp.substring(0, i);
    }
  }
  return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code `i` goes from `0` to `length-1`, and then attempts to take `substring(i, i+6)`. When `i` is above `length-6`, this would cause the out of bounds exception. Changing the loop condition to `str.length()-6` should address this problem.

The check for the `length` to be above `11` *inside* the loop does not look correct.

Comment: but when I change it to length()-5 (which is the first point when there is no out of bounds exception), it won't work.  So how do i fix it?

Comment: @user2036340 I would try removing the `str.length() >= 11` check. A simpler solution is to use `str.replaceAll("bread", "")` to do the replacements.

Comment: but i only want the characters that are in between the two breads (when there are two breads), so if i just do:

'public String getSandwich(String str) {
  String newString = str.replaceAll("bread", "");
  return newString;
}'

it wont work

Comment: @user2036340 Then you could use str.replaceAll("bread(.*?)bread", "\\1").

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getSandwich(String str) {
  String newString = "";
  int i1 = str.indexOf("bread");
  int i2 = str.lastIndexOf("bread");
  if(i1 != i2){
    newString = str.substring(i1 + 5, i2);
  }
  return newString;
}
```