# Code not running properly - middle of word

Tags: java

I'm writing a code to see if there's xyz in the middle of a given string.  This works if xyz appears once, but when it appears more than once, it won't always work.

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  if (str.length() <= 2) {
    return false;
  }
  int count1 = 0;
  int count2 = 0;
  for (int i=(str.length()-2)/2; i<str.length()-2; i++) {
    if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("xyz")) {
      count1 = str.substring(0, i).length();
      count2 = str.substring(i+3).length();
    }
  }
  if (count1 == count2 || count1+1 == count2 || count2+1 == count1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Your program returns `true` even if the input is `abcd`

Comment: Why not use the string contains method?

Comment: It's the fourth question you ask in a single hour. Take some time to think, debug, read the javadoc, experiment instead of asking others to fix your code. That's how you'll learn.

Comment: Instead of posting all your queries on site. Go and read book. Sorry for rash words. Few hours ago you posted query http://stackoverflow.com/q/15462061/814074. It will be better you read book first.

Comment: @JeffStorey from what I understand, he wants to know whether a string is in the exact middle of another.

Comment: Oh in that case indexOf would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
int middle = (str.length() - 2) / 2;
return "xyz".equals(str.substring(middle, middle + 3));
```

If the length of `str` is an even number, there may be one more letter before `xyz` than after. If you want that to be after instead of before, you must subtract three instead of two. If you want to forbid this completely, you first need an `if` check on the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check out the [Java SE 6 api docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).
Step 2: Read the entry on String.
Step 3: try this: String.split("xyz");

Comment: where would i put that?

Comment: perform steps 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is overly complicated... You should use String.split("xyz"), then check the size of the returned array, and if it's 2, check that both parts are equal:

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  String[] temp = str.split("xyz");
  return temp.length == 2 ? temp[0].length == temp[1].length : false;
}
```